# Storing binary files in Google Gears DB?

Tags: javascript, google-gears

Can I store binary files in the Google Gears DB?

For example an image file from the users hard drive.

Answer (score -1):

You could try [BlobAPI - An opaque handle to binary data](http://code.google.com/p/gears/wiki/BlobAPI).